# Deriving marginal likelihood formula

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, marginal-probability

The formula for marginal likelihood is the following:

$ p(D | m) = \int P(D | \theta)p(\theta | m)d\theta $

But if I try to simplify the right-hand-side, how would I prove this equality

$ = \int \frac{p(D, \theta)}{p(\theta)}\frac{p(\theta, m)}{p(m)}d\theta $

... and so on? I can't seem to simplify it. I can't just "remove" $ \theta $ here right like you would do if there was only one expression? As in this isn't the same as:

$ P(D)\frac{P(m)}{P(m)} = P(D)? $

Comment: You want to be performing the marginalisation over $\theta$ so you want to rearrange your integrand so that $\theta$ is the argument of the density function and doesn't appear as a variable being conditioned on.

Comment: @Nadiels Can you show what you mean? I don't see how I could expand it more than I've done in step 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the marginal likelihood is more of a definition than a result, what you do always have from basic probability theory is the marginalisation
$$
p(D|m)=\int p(D, \theta | m)d\theta, \tag{1}
$$
so there is an assumption that $p(D | \theta, m) = p(D | \theta)$ - this is a hierarchical modelling set up.

Since we know $(1)$ my comment is just that as quickly as possible you want to go
$$
p(D|\theta)p(\theta|m) = p(D, \theta |m),
$$
so instead of an expansion like you have considered you are actually wanting to condense everything to a joint density.

Comment: Okay, but how did you get $ p(D|\theta)p(\theta|m) = P(D, \theta | m)? $

Comment: 'Cause $p(D, \theta | m ) = p(D | \theta, m)p(\theta | m)$ but $p(D |\theta, m) = p(D | \theta)$ by assumption.

Comment: Alright, then I get it. It was the assumption that confused me. Thanks!

Comment: No worries - I think that assumption is actually responsible for a *lot* of confusion when it comes to the marginal likelihood